# Breaking Nunjucks Loop

Tags: node.js, loops, express, break, nunjucks

I've racked my brain in all directions but still no solution. Maybe someone has some advice?

I have the following block in an ExpressJS app using Nunjucks as the templating engine.

```
{%- for course in courses -%}
    {%- for rcourse in report.courses -%}
        {%- if rcourse.id == course.id -%}
            <li {{ 'class="column-pre"' if loop.last else ''}}><span>Cool!</span></li>
        {%- else -%}
            <li></li>
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

**My problem:** I need to `break` the inner `report.courses` loop when the conditional proves truth-y. Basically, the moment that I print the non-empty `<li>` line, I need to jump to the next iteration of the `courses` loop.

I know that Nunjucks does't have a `break` for loops like Jinja2, Nunjucks' variables are scoped (so I can't set a sentinel-like variable that gets modified in the `if/else` statement), nor can I append to an array so that I can use `array.length` as a way to determine if I should print the `<li></li>` line.

*Maybe someone has a clever solution?*

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentinel-like variable would not be affected by scoping:

```
{% for course in courses %}
    {% set searchrcourse = true %}
    {% for rcourse in report.courses %}
        {% if searchrcourse %}
            {% if rcourse.id == course.id %}
                <li {{ 'class="column-pre"' if loop.last else ''}}><span>Cool!</span></li>
                {% set searchrcourse = false %}
            {% else %}
                <li></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```